# Makefile rule is not executing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to compile Atmel's Bitcloud (WSNDemo) on Ubuntu 14.04.

The makefile (http://pastebin.com/4gGcGRvY) however seems not executing a rule on my computer.

The problem is that it doesn't start the compiler only the linker. And of course the linker then can't find the objects.

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)
```

is never called (line 187 in makefile) upon running this:

```
make -n -f Makefile_All_StdlinkSec_MegaRf_Atmega2564rfr2_16Mhz_Gcc all APP_NAME=WSNDemo
```

However if I specify the object and also the source by hand (in line 192), then it runs fine:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/ofdIntFlashRead.o: ../../../../BitCloud/Components/HAL/drivers/OFD/src/ofdIntFlashRead.s
```

Note: all source files are in the right place.

So I don't understand why the pattern matching is not working.

Comment: If you reduced this to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would save us a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misleading you guys.

The mistake was in the Makefile. It came from Windows and the author unintentionally changed a filename to lowercase, and then the makefile couldn't find it on Linux (but it was okay on Windows).

Thank you for your time though.