# Makefile rule is not executing in Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, pattern-matching, posix, rules

I am trying to build the Atmel BitCloud v3.2 sample application Blink with the [makefile](http://pastebin.com/yXpfuSc5) in Linux and Mac. Everything works fine in Windows. But in Posix-like systems the following lines are not working:

```
all: directories images root_files size
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(filter %/$(subst .o,.c,$(notdir $@)), $(SRCS)) -o $@
```

Therefore, the compiler is not being executed and object files are not being created. As the result the linker displays error messages such as

> avr-gcc: error: All_MegaRf_Atmega256rfr2_8Mhz_Gcc/Obj/blink.o: No such file or directory

The line `$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)` is the source of the problem.

If I substitute it with smth like `$(OBJ_PATH)/blink.o: ../../src/blink.c` the corresponding object-file is being successfully created.

I was even able to build the whole application by manually setting build targets as follows:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)/blink.o: ../../src/blink.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(filter %/$(subst .o,.c,$(notdir $@)), $(SRCS)) -o $@
$(OBJ_PATH)/stdPdsEvents.o: ../../../../BitCloud/Components/PersistDataServer/std/src/stdPdsEvents.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(filter %/$(subst .o,.c,$(notdir $@)), $(SRCS)) -o $@
```

for all the .c files in the project.

The list of sources on the other hand is defined like this:

```
SRCS = \
 ../../src/blink.c \
 ../../../../BitCloud/Components/PersistDataServer/std/src/stdPdsMemAccess.c \
 ../../../../BitCloud/Components/PersistDataServer/std/src/stdPdsTimer.c \
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why is the pattern matching not working and how to recover it.

Note: Similar topic has already been open [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723554/makefile-rule-is-not-executing), but the solution found by th author himself wasn't explained well in my opinion, so I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo: Your recent edit seems to have removed semantically important whitespace.  Please refrain from editing code in languages you are not familiar with.  Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee My bad, I was trying to replace backpack escapes by code indent. Should i revert to the previous one ?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo No need; I already restored the lost tabs.  Thanks for being so quick to respond.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the edit then :)

Comment: It's not clear to me why the Makefile is not working, and what exactly you mean by POSIX.  The Makefile uses GNU Make syntax extensions, so clearly will not work with POSIX Make.

Answer (score 0):

The construct to have each object file depend on *all* source files and then have the compilation step fish the *actually* useful file out of the list of sources is quite dubious.  A better approach would be to generate a Makefile snippet and include it, something like this:

```
makefile.d:
    echo "$(SRCS)" \
    | tr ' ' '\n' \
    | sed -n 's%\(.*\)/\([^/]*\)\.c$$%$(OBJ_PATH)/\2.o: \1/\2.c%p' >$@
include makefile.d
```

All details of `sed` are not properly standardized, so you may be better off rewriting the substitution in Perl or something.  The beef here is how we capture the path and the base name and generate a specific rule for each dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it finally.
In order to make it compile both in Windows and Linux one should change the makefile as shown below:

```
objects := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))
$(objects): $(SRCS)
#$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(filter %/$(subst .o,.c,$(notdir $@)), $(SRCS)) -o $@
```

where `$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRCS)` shall be commented or removed.
After having done this way the project can be built under linux or mac and under windows both in Atmel Studio 6.2 and Atmel Studio 7. The latter was not able to build just like it was not possible in linux or mac.